# How to remove all activity in Stack when press back button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have a list of activities A - B -C -D - E and more, for example final activity is K. I want clear all these activities in stack when i press BACK button. How can i do ? In fact, i over ride

```
onBackPress(){ 
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish();
}
```

but only current activity is deleted and application exit. Then, i come back application, it resume activity before K. I want it start from begining when i re-open app. I think the reason here is because the list of activities in stack still are stored, so i want to clear all stack when clicking BACK button. Any suggestions ? thank you very much !

Answer (score 6):

There is method called finishAffinity() for finishing all activity.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
  super.onBackPressed();
  this.finishAffinity();}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call your activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` inside your `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent it = new Intent(YouCurrentActivity.this, YourFinalActivity.class);
    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(it);
    finish();
}
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 2):

Either use the `noHistory` flag in the manifest or finish each activity yourself when the user navigates away.

```
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Another solution, maybe the best, if you have so many overlaying `Activities`: use only one `Activity` and handle the content in `Fragments`. This way you are in control what exactly you want to show when the user hits the back button.

Answer (score 0):

In **API level 11 or greater**, use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on Intent to clear all the activity stack.
Add this code on your `onBackPressed()` method,

```
> This launch mode can also be used to
```

> good effect in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to
>   start the root activity of a task, it
>   will bring any currently running
>   instance of that task to the
>   foreground, and then clear it to its
>   root state. This is especially useful,
>   for example, when launching an
>   activity from the notification
>   manager.

So your code to launch `B` would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```